# How to make a pandas dataframe with nested columns from a list of nested dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list `data` containing dicts with this schema:

```
{'id': '123',
 '2020-06-15': {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4},
 '2020-06-16': {'A': 5, 'B': 6, 'C': 7, 'D': 8}}
```

When I use `df = pandas.DataFrame(data).set_index("id")` to create a dataframe  I get this table:

```
                           2020-06-15                        2020-06-16
id
123  {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4}  {'A': 5, 'B': 6, 'C': 7, 'D': 8}
```

And when I use `df = pandas.json_normalize(data)` I get this:

```
     id  2020-06-15.A  2020-06-15.B  2020-06-15.C  2020-06-15.D  2020-06-16.A  2020-06-16.B  2020-06-16.C  2020-06-16.D
0   123             1             2             3             4             5             6             7             8
```

But preferred result is this:

```
     2020-06-15  2020-06-16
id   A  B  C  D  A  B  C  D
123  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Is there any way to make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create index by `id` column and then use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = df.set_index('id')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
print (df)
    2020-06-15          2020-06-16         
             A  B  C  D          A  B  C  D
id                                         
123          1  2  3  4          5  6  7  8
```

Comment: Just a note to the OP : splitting columns with expand=True creates a multiIndex, which is your end goal